# Pyspark Data healing

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyspark

I have a spark Data frame where I am trying to copy down the values in a column when there is an empty record for a value.

I tried using the below code:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession, functions as F

data = [(8194, 'Closed'),
        (8194, ''),
        (8194, ''),
        (8196, 'Draft'),
        (8196, ''),
        (8197, 'open'),
        (8197, ''),
        (8197, '')]
base_df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["id","status"])

window_spec = Window.partitionBy("id").orderBy(F.col("id"))
l_id = F.lag("status").over(window_spec)
base_df = base_df.withColumn("status", F.when((base_df["status"] == "") | base_df["status"].isNull(), l_id).otherwise(base_df["status"]))

base_df.show()
```

This code is only updating one record. Can someone help me achieve the desired sample output.

[Sample Input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DHcaw.png)

[Sample Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DEPzq.png)

[tried code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y8qlq.png)

Comment: the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: updated the code.

Answer (score 0):

You could check the **last** function [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.last.html).

> The function by default returns the last values it sees. It will
> return the last non-null value it sees when ignoreNulls is set to
> true. If all values are null, then null is returned.

Note that in your case you created the DataFrame using "" instead None, this will not work because "" is considering as string.

Check this implementation:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession, functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

data = [(8194, 'Closed'),
        (8194, None),
        (8194, None),
        (8196, 'Draft'),
        (8196, None),
        (8197, 'open'),
        (8197, None),
        (8197, None)]
base_df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["id","status"])

base_df.show()
```

The return is:

```
+----+------+
|  id|status|
+----+------+
|8194|Closed|
|8194|  null|
|8194|  null|
|8196| Draft|
|8196|  null|
|8197|  open|
|8197|  null|
|8197|  null|
+----+------+
```

Based on this, see the last function in practice:

```
window_spec = Window.partitionBy("id").orderBy(F.col("id"))

new_base_df =  base_df.withColumn("status", F.last("status", True).over(windowSpec))
new_base_df.show()

+----+------+
|  id|status|
+----+------+
|8194|Closed|
|8194|Closed|
|8194|Closed|
|8196| Draft|
|8196| Draft|
|8197|  open|
|8197|  open|
|8197|  open|
+----+------+
```

Comment: when I have the below data and run with the above code. the 1st row Status is also getting updated 'Open'. how to make sure only the last status is copied down and does not effect the above rows.


data = [(8194, 'Closed'),
        (8194, 'Open'),
        (8194, null),
        (8196, 'Draft'),
        (8196, null),
        (8197, 'open'),
        (8197, null),
        (8197, null)]

Comment: attached the code snippet I tried as my data frame has empty values converted them to nulls and then tried healing